# Add to cart functionality in react js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not able to get the selected items data in the cart functionality
[i want to get the particular item on clicking this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCJzO.jpg)
[i am getting this in the cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rHD1.png)

i want to get the selected item from the product page on the cart page for billing purposes.I have created a new empty array but it is not storing the entire selected value's data.
github repo link: https://github.com/Amala06/canteen.git

My App.js is

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Foodcard from './pages/Foodcard';
import Food from './pages/Food';
import Navbar from './pages/Navbar';
import Menu from './Menu';
import React from 'react';
import Bill from './pages/Bill';
import Mainnav from './component/Mainnav'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routeroot from './Routepath/Routhpath';
import Routhpath from './Routepath/Routhpath';
function App() {

  const {productItems}=Menu;
  const [cartItems,setCartItems]=React.useState([]);
  // const{id,title,image,price,category}=Items;
  const handleAddProduct=(product)=>{
    // console.log(product.id,'hh');
   
    const ProductExist=cartItems.find((item)=>item.id===product.id);
    if(ProductExist){
      setCartItems(cartItems.map((item)=>item.id===product.id?
      {...ProductExist,quantity:ProductExist.quantity + 1}:item)
      );
    }else{
        setCartItems([...cartItems,{...product,quantity:1}])
      }
      console.log(product,'shubham');
      // console.log(cartItems,'sona')
    
  

    // const titleExist=cartItems.find((item)=>item.title===product.title);
    // if(titleExist){
    //   setCartItems(cartItems.map((item)=>item.title===product.title?
    //   {...titleExist,title:titleExist.title + "s"}:item)
    //   );
    // }else{
    //     setCartItems([...cartItems,{...product,title:1}])
    //   }
    //   console.log(product,'shubham');
    
    }
    const onAdd=(productItems)=>{
      console.log("added");
      const exist=cartItems.find((x)=>x.id===productItems.id);
      if(exist){
        const newCartItems=cartItems.map((x)=>
        x.id===product.id?{...exist,qty:exist.qt+1}:x);
        setCartItems(newCartItems);
      }
      else{
        const newCartItems=[...cartItems,{...product,qty:1}];
        setCartItems(newCartItems)
      }
    }




      // console.log(cartItems,'sona')}
    
  return (
  <>


  <BrowserRouter>

  <Mainnav countCartItems={cartItems.length} />
  <Routhpath productItems={productItems} cartItems={cartItems} handleAddProduct={handleAddProduct} onAdd={onAdd}/>
  </BrowserRouter>




  </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

this is Product display page

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';
import Menu from '../Menu';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import arr from './Arr';
import Navbar from './Navbar';

const Bill=({productItems,handleAddProduct,onAdd,cartItems})=> {
 
const {id,image,title,category,price}=productItems;
  const uniqueList=[...new Set(
    productItems.map((curElem)=>{
      return curElem.category;
    })
    
  ),"All",]
  const[foodData,setfoodData]=React.useState(productItems);
  const[quoteList,setquoteList]=React.useState(uniqueList);
  const[select,setfoodSelect]=React.useState(productItems);

  const filterItem=(title)=>
  {
    if(title==="All"){
      setfoodData(productItems);
      return;
    }
   
    const updatedList=productItems.filter((curElem)=>{
      return curElem.category===title;
    })
    setfoodData(updatedList);
  }

  const selectItem=(selected)=>{
    const selecteditemlist=productItems.filter((curElem)=>{
      return curElem.selected===true;
    })
    setfoodSelect(selecteditemlist)
  }


    return (

        <>
       
        bill
        <Navbar filterItem={filterItem} quoteList={quoteList}/>

        <section className='main-container' required='quotes' style={{display:"flex",flexDirection:"row",flexWrap:"wrap",marginLeft:"3rem"}}>
{foodData.map((curElem)=>{
  return(<> <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key={curElem.id} productItems={productItems} item={cartItems.find((x)=>x.id===productItems.id)} onAdd={onAdd} >
  <Card.Img variant="top" src={curElem.image}  />
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{curElem.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
    ₹ {curElem.price} ({curElem.category})
    </Card.Text>
    {/* <Button  variant="danger" className='m-1'  onClick={()=>{setid(curElem.id);settitle(curElem.title ); setprice(curElem.price);console.log(id,title,price);arr.push(id,title,price);console.log(arr);return id; }} >Add to Cart */}
    {/* { item={title,price,category}} */}

    <Button  variant="danger" className='m-1' onClick={()=>handleAddProduct(productItems)} >Add to Cart


        </Button>
         {/* <Button  variant="danger" className='m-1' onClick={onAdd} >Add to Cart


</Button> */}
       


  </Card.Body>
</Card></>)


})}
  </section>      
        
        </>
   
    );
  }
  
  export default Bill;
```

this is my cart page

```
import React from 'react'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Card from 'react-bootstrap/Card';

const Cart = ({cartItems,handleAddProduct,onAdd}) => {
    for (let index = 0; index < cartItems.length; index++) {
     console.log(cartItems[index])
        
    }
    const {id,image,title,category,price}=cartItems;

  return (

    <>Cart
        {cartItems.length===0 && (<div>
            No items are added
        </div>)}
<div>


{console.log(cartItems.id)}
{cartItems.map((curElem)=>{
  return(<> 
  <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} >
    {console.log(curElem,"hhjjjj")}
  {/* <Card.Img variant="top" src={curElem.image}  /> */}
  <Card.Body>
    <Card.Title>{curElem.title}</Card.Title>
    <Card.Text>
    ₹ {curElem.price} ({curElem.quantity})
    </Card.Text>
    {/* <Button  variant="danger" className='m-1'  onClick={()=>{setid(curElem.id);settitle(curElem.title ); setprice(curElem.price);console.log(id,title,price);arr.push(id,title,price);console.log(arr);return id; }} >Add to Cart */}
    <Button  variant="danger" className='m-1'  >Add to Cart


        </Button>
       


  </Card.Body>
</Card></>)


})}
</div>



    </>
  )
}

export default Cart
```

i want that on clicking add to cart button,i want the particular item to be displayed in cart page
[i want to get the particular item on clicking this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCJzO.jpg)
[i am getting this in the cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rHD1.png)